# how to add data to custom content type using node with codeing

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

i have drupal site with custom content type called donation and i have 4 step registration form which contains the data for the custom content type,i want to add forms data in to custom content type node how can i do that i try way like this

```
$nid = 1;
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->donationname = '.$data1.';
$node->donationitem = '.$data2.';
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper method is

```
  $body_text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.';

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title    = 'Node Created Programmatically on ' . date('c');
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $body_text;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($body_text);
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';

  $path = 'content/my-lipsum-' . date('YmdHis');
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

  node_save($node);
```

**To Add custom fields**

```
// Let's add some CCK/Fields API field. This is pretty similar to the body example 
$node->field_custom_name[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a custom field value';
// If your custom field has a format, don't forget to define it here
$node->field_custom_name[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'This is a custom field value';
```

[How to programmatically create/manage node in drupal 7](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/programmatically-create-node-drupal-7)